# Does the eclipse compiler have an equivalent of the javac tree api

Tags: eclipse, javac

When an annotation processor is invoked by javac you can access the [tree api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/) - which is useful for finding things like branch statements etc etc using a tree visitor.

Unfortunately when the same annotation processor is invoked from the eclipse compiler the tree api is unavailable.

Does the eclipse compiler have a roughly equivalent api? In particular I'd like to be able to detect if/while/for statements using a visitor.

Comment: Look at the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get the AST without being a plugin? I 'd love to create an AnnotationProcessor that works with both javac and the eclipse compiler.